# PHP, upload file on image click

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code

```
<?php
// Upload pictures
$folder = '../images/tmp';
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name){
    if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1 && (false !== strpos($_FILES['files']['type'][$i],'image'))){
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $folder.'/'.$name)){
            // Redirect to the Upload form
            header('Location: osi_upload.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

to upload images on localhost. After that, I using this code:

```
<?php
    $i = -1;
  foreach(glob($folder.'/*') as $filename){
        $file[++$i] = $filename;
    } ?>

    <form action="draft.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="img-frm" method="post"><?php
    // Medium and large devices
    switch($gallery){
        case 1:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 1-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      for($n=0;$n<=$i;$n++){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
        <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
          <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
          <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]" ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
        </label>
        <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
...
```

to preview the images I've uploaded. If needed, I can click on one of those images to open the upload file dialog box to change the corresponding image. To change image, I'm using the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Change clicked pictures
    if(!$('#img-frm input[type="file"]')){
        return;
    }
    $('#img-frm input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        // Get the input number
        var str = this.id.split("[");
        var i = str[1].substr(0,str[1].length-1);
        var s = 'img-pict[' + i + ']';
        // Get the new picture address
        var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        // Preview the new picture
        document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;
        str = $(this).val().split("\\");
        var n = str.length;
        s = 'img-name[' + i + ']';
        document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = str[n-1];
    });
});
```

All those codes works fine. My problem is about uploading the replacing image after I clicked on a image preview to change it. I can't figure out how, in PHP I prefer, I can change the image on the server. I tried to submit the form after the change, but in the receiving file, I got nothing! Blank! Can someone help.

Maybe it's important to know that the rest of the form is made of text inputs, areas, select and date inputs. When I make changes to those, I get a post on my receiving file for those other form elements. The changes made to the preview images are not posted.

**OK! I THINK I'M IN THE BEGINNING OF A WAY THROUGH THIS MESS!!!**
Assuming that javascript has some pain to handle $_FILES array from post forms, I've added a hidden input in the HTML file:

```
<label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
          <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
          <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]" ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
        </label>
        <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?> id=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
```

to retrieve the file url after posting. I've change my javascript file to handle the hidden input:

```
$('#img-frm input[type="file"]').change(function(){
// Get the input number
var str = this.id.split("[");
var i = str[1].substr(0,str[1].length-1);
var s = 'img-pict[' + i + ']';
// Get the new picture address
var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
// Preview the new picture
document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;
s = 'img-hidden[' + i + ']';
document.getElementById(s).value = new_img;
str = $(this).val().split("\\");
var n = str.length;
s = 'img-name[' + i + ']';
document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = str[n-1];
});
```

and I've got this:

```
Array ( [img-hidden] => Array ( [0] => blob:http://localhost/f8e7a5af-76fa-4da1-b489-387b55395873 [1] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio02.jpg [2] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio03.jpg [3] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio04.jpg [4] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio05.jpg [5] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio06.jpg [6] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio07.jpg [7] => ../images/tmp/templatemo_portfolio08.jpg )
```

Note that the first index in the array **[img-hidden]** is a **blob** that's the url of the new image (remember after I've clicked on an image to change it). Is it possible to upload that image using that url? How? (Note that all images need to be uploaded in their final destination, but I don't have trouble handling the other files. Only that I don't know the **blobs**)

Comment: Are `#img-frm input[type="file"]` in a form? If so, you can submit a form with javascript. Something like `document.getElementById("img-frm").submit();` (assuming `img-frm` is form id).

Comment: As you can see in the HTML code above, #img-frm is the form id and input[type="file"] is an input inside the form. I already tried to submit the form with javascript, but the result stays the same. I wonder if the problem is not specific to images. Does javascript $post variable handle $_files array?

Comment: Suppose you missed name for input `<input type="file" id="<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>" name="<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>">`

Comment: I had already correct that. But the result stays the same

Comment: I would check you are sending the proper headers when submitting the form, specifically it sends as multipart/form-data: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YJYPm.png

Comment: I don't really understand your point. The form enctype is **multipart/form-data**

Answer (score 0):

I am confused :D
After a lot of searching,I cancelled everything I've done and re-tried the original code and it is working. I think I had a typo or something like that in the receiving file. I think about `print_r($_FILE);` instead of `print_r($_FILES);` I don't know.

In fact, the actual challenge was to upload images to the server after previewing them for modification (eventually). Several pictures are uploaded at once and displayed according to a particular canvas depending on how many they are and their sizes.

Instead of using a very complicated (for me at least!) AJAX API to communicate with the server I preferred looking for a solution where every language can play its own game as it was meant to be.

So, I used the HTML to implement the fact that I can click on a image and open an upload dialog box to select another image to replace the previous one.

```
<label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
          <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
        </label>
        <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
```

`label` input with `for=` attribute is the key.

To make the replacement to act without reloading the file, of course I used javascript with a bit of JQuery (not necessary but funny)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Change clicked pictures
    if(!$('#img-frm input[type="file"]')){
        return;
    }
    $('#img-frm input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        // Get the input number
        var str = this.id.split("[");
        var i = str[1].substr(0,str[1].length-1);
        var s = 'img-pict[' + i + ']';
        // Get the new picture address
        var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

        // Preview the new picture
        document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;
        str = $(this).val().split("\\");
        var n = str.length;
        s = 'img-name[' + i + ']';
        document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = str[n-1];
    });
});
```

In the line `var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);`, the URL of the image you choose to replace the preview is generated and in the line `document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;`, the image is loaded in the place of the preview you clicked on before. The path is send by the form and a `$_FILES` array is created. You can use PHP now to upload.

Despite my ridiculous typo, I hope this will help. I've seen tons of weird answers about similar issues through the net.

Comment: $_FILE doesn't exist, so that's why you got an error. Next time make sure that you display_errors when working in local.